# PTVS: unit test source path

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing, ptvs

Using Python Tools for Visual Studio, I created a 'project from exisiting source'.  I *can* run it's main application file, but every unit test (automatically discovered!) fails to start:

```
ImportError: No Module named src.xyz.unit.TestThisAndThat
```

My python sources are in a folder called 'src', which isn't a package.  In this case, I'm looking for a way to configure the 'source' path.

Summarizing:

How can I configure the source path to use for running unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

One option, though not so scalable, is to add path of your project - '...path_to/src' to the system variable PYTHONPATH and restart ptvs.